# Suppress system() output in R

Tags: r

I wanna apply the `invisible()` function behavior to an output I got in my script that goes like this `system("cmd.exe", input = command)`. However, even when using invisible, the output still shows in console. Is there any way to hide it?

EDIT: I'm running `curl` in the command to download a webpage and the output is the expected curl output.

EDIT2: Reproducible example

```
url <- "www.google.com"
command <- paste0('curl "', 
                  url,
                  '"',
                  ' -H "Pragma: no-cache" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Cookie: uupid69991=eb4c8ec5-1f94-4cf5-957d-e477a778f79c; uupid99993=eb4c8ec5-1f94-4cf5-957d-e477a778f79c; uupid89991=1; uupid79991=Fee_Based_Role; locale=en; uupid99991=1903 x 1012; IVZSESSIONID=CEHrDvYqpDuQ-zwy8YZpWwm1RWZHY3DGq4V7elBfxcH87XFFo-J_^! -175310928; _ga=GA1.2.1974800928.1524362050; _gid=GA1.2.1544243785.1524362050" -H "Connection: keep-alive" --compressed',
                  ' > google.html')

invisible(system("cmd.exe", input = command))
```

Console Output:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.371]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\gonza\OneDrive\Documents\etfcmfa>curl "www.google.com" -H "Pragma: no-cache" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Cookie: uupid69991=eb4c8ec5-1f94-4cf5-957d-e477a778f79c; uupid99993=eb4c8ec5-1f94-4cf5-957d-e477a778f79c; uupid89991=1; uupid79991=Fee_Based_Role; locale=en; uupid99991=1903 x 1012; IVZSESSIONID=CEHrDvYqpDuQ-zwy8YZpWwm1RWZHY3DGq4V7elBfxcH87XFFo-J_^! -175310928; _ga=GA1.2.1974800928.1524362050; _gid=GA1.2.1544243785.1524362050" -H "Connection: keep-alive" --compressed > google.html
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   231  100   231    0     0    982      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   982
```

Comment: what output is displayed?  is it a message, warning, error, or the output itself?

Comment: @MelissaKey it's a curl command output when downloading a page

Comment: This is too vague. "a webpage"? What webpage? What code? And exactly what output is "expected"?

Comment: Added another edit with an example

Comment: @Dason intern did it!! Thanks! If you put your comment as an answer I can pick it as resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `intern=TRUE` in your system call.  From the `system` help page:

```
intern  
a logical (not NA) which indicates whether to capture the output of the command as an R character vector.
```

Once you do that you can either use invisible or just store the results to keep them from being printed.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the "ignore.stdout" or "ignore.stderr" attributes (or both) to TRUE might work (may be specific to Unix operating systems). "ignore.stdout" suppresses messages written to "stdout" and "ignore.stderr" suppresses messages written to "stderr".

So:

```
system(some_command, ignore.stdout = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sink` function to divert output in R.

```
> curl::curl('https://stackoverflow.com/')
A connection with                                        
description "https://stackoverflow.com/"
class       "curl"                      
mode        "r"                         
text        "text"                      
opened      "closed"                    
can read    "yes"                       
can write   "no"                        
> sink(file="nul") # set file = '/dev/null' if using Unix-based OS
> curl::curl('https://stackoverflow.com/') # no output
```

If you set `file` to something else, it will print output to that file instead of the console.

Comment: This is what I wanted to avoid since I do want some part of the code to output in console. Just not that. If there's no other possible solution I'll just sink, unsink that part of the code.

Comment: is it really this difficult to suppress output from R?